# Logical operation in variable value

Tags: php, logic, logical-operators

I have a variable, which hold the logical operations. 
**{$logic="1 &&  || 1";}**
i want to perform logical operations in that variable.
if i do the below scenario, it displays wrong result.
**{if($logic) { echo "TRUE";} else {echo "FALSE";}}**
how can i do the logical operation the value stored in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eval](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.eval.php) PHP function:

```
$logic="1 || 1;";
echo eval($logic) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. But my below code returns always false. {$logical = "1 && 0 || 1;"} {echo eval($logical) ? 'TRUE': 'FALSE'}

Comment: Thank You Sergiu. I have found the solution. Need to return the eval string will give the correct result. {$result = eval("return (".$logic.");"); // $result will be true}.